# How to clear focus and remove keyboard on Android?

Tags: android

I have a EditText control.
If I tap it the softkeyboard will popup however when I press "enter/ok/return" then the EditText control  it still has focus and the keyboard up.
How do I close the softkeyboard and remove focus from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try doing `SetFocus()` on another element in your layout.

If you are talking about the "enter/ok/return" button on the keyboard itself you may have to set up a `KeyListener` on the `EditText` control in order to know when to `SetFocus()` on another element.

Comment: I understand that this is the solution given by many people, but I don't like it, because instead of input.clearFocus() simply working (i.e. clearing the focus from that input), you now have to set the focus to something else!? It just seems counter-intuitive.

Answer (score 20):

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editTextField.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: This will only hide the keyboard.  It will not remove focus.

Answer (score 13):

In the layout XML file, specify an imeOption on your EditText:

```
android:imeOptions="actionGo"
```

Next, add an action listener to your EditText in the Activity's java file

```
    mYourEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO) {
                // hide virtual keyboard
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mYourEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Where mYourEditText is an EditText object

Comment: Hmm thank you. but im a suposed to write the imeOpt in the layout or the edittext?
and i got error on EditorInfo, any idea?

Comment: Can you explain the EditorInfo?

Comment: This will dismiss the keyboard but will not remove focus in all cases.  IE android will request focus on the first available view that can focus.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your EditText XML has :

```
android:id="@+id/myEditText"    
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

Then set listener to your EditText (with Kotlin, and from a fragment):

```
myEditText.setOnEditorActionListener({ v, actionId, event ->
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                myEditText.clearFocus()
                val imm = activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view!!.windowToken, 0)    
            }
            false
        })
```

Answer (score 2):

```
private void hideDefaultKeyboard() {
    activity.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
   //you have got lot of methods here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must catch the action en OnEditorActionListener

If you are in an Activity use:

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener((viewAux, actionId, eventKey) -> {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
            //Remove focus
            editText.clearFocus();
            //Hide the keyboard
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
```

If you are in a Fragment add requireContext

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener((viewAux, actionId, eventKey) -> {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
            editText.clearFocus();
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)requireContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

A Kotlin solution that works for me, removes all active focus and close the soft keyboard.
Set android:focusableInTouchMode="true" on your parent layout.
In my case I have a ScrollView as well. I am setting view.clearFocus() in its touch event listener. This will clear all the focus on any touched textview. Then I proceed to close the soft keyboard on screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    ...
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" //<--- this is important

    tools:context=".SomFragment">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view_container"
        ...
        >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sone_text_1"
            ...
             />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sone_text_2"
            ...
             />
```

Then in your class

```
scroll_view_container.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
        view.clearFocus()
        hideSoftKeyboard()
        true
    }

private fun hideSoftKeyboard() {
    val windowToken = view?.rootView?.windowToken
    windowToken?.let{
        val imm = requireContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(it, 0)
    }
}
```