# Show/Hide hint text for editText when enable fullsreen mode

Tags: android, android-edittext

How show hint text when open edittext in fullscreen mode?
I'm can show hint text with OnFocusChangeListener.

```
 editChangeName.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
            editChangeName.setHint(b ? getResources().getString(R.string.name) : "");
        }
    });
```

But.

How hide hint text after closing edittext?

Comment: I've provided an answer to this in this question (this is a duplicate, but I don't want to flag because it already has a (different) accepted answer). https://stackoverflow.com/a/52975488/3238938

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   // assuming you have a EditText view with id 
   View viewById = getView().findViewById(R.id.editTextId);
   if(viewById!=null) {
           //  set listener to this view "many views could share one listener"
           viewById.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
               @Override
                public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                    // if view match id &&  has no focus 
                    if(v.getId() == R.id.editTextId && !hasFocus) 
                             // clear hint 
                             ((EditText) v).setHint(null);
                    // else show hint 
                }
          });
   }
```

hasFocus <- as name says

- has (true) ->  show
- doesn't have (false) -> hide

if you are not sure if view by id is one you assign to an edit text do a check ( double check will not hurt)

```
  if (EditText.class.isAssignableFrom(v.getClass()))
     // do cast  
     EditText editText = (EditText) v;
```

*This code is correct. But. How hide hinttext, after closing softkeyboard.. edittext have focus – Eugenu Yansky*

[Detecting when user has dismissed the soft keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3425932/detecting-when-user-has-dismissed-the-soft-keyboard/)

[How to remove focus without setting focus to another control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117967/how-to-remove-focus-without-setting-focus-to-another-control)

[How to clear focus and remove keyboard on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235070/how-to-clear-focus-and-remove-keyboard-on-android)

Comment: This code is correct. But. How hide hinttext, after closing softkeyboard.. edittext have focus

Comment: move focus to next element, clear focus - it's your choice :) see edit

Comment: @eugenu-yansky if i helped vote up and accept answer :)